# Driving from Todtmoos to Freiburg im Breisgau

Tags: germany, driving

If I look at Google Maps to go from Todtmoos to Freiburg im Breisgau, one of the options goes right past Schauinsland; it looks like quite a wiggly road with a fair amount of elevation.

Streetview doesn't seem to have made it to this area yet; is this road easily drive-able by someone who is an experienced driver, but not used to driving on the right and not keen on vertiginous drops next to the edge of the road?

Comment: There is quite a bit of stuff in google, like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynZKM-UQLGs).

Comment: Mind the access limitations for motorbikes: From April 1st to November 1st, motorbikes are not allowed on saturdays, sundays and public holidays.

Comment: @Janka, I won't be on a motorbike, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: On such a road, as a driver, you should keep your eyes on the road and not look left and right. You most probably won't notice the drops next to the road :) . I won't comment on "drivability" though, as includes too much subjectivity IMO.

Comment: I've occasionally used the Schauinsland road, which, in my view, is nothing to worry about. The metal planking (usually on the other side when going towards Freiburg) is there for a reason, but you're going through woodland and won't notice much of a drop beyond the roadside. The worst thing might be having to endure impatient motorists behind you or an over-cautious slow driver ahead. That said, I can't tell whether a 'wiggly' road could be an issue when you're not used to driving on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I’m happy to say I did this drive last week and it was no problem at all (and very beautiful). The comment from @user108733 on the question stating that the drive is predominantly through woodland and any drops are not particularly noticeable is 100% correct. The  YouTube link posted by @Tomas By was also very helpful to me in showing the nature of the road.